# RIP Christopher Lee

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

Christopher Lee, best known for his portrayal of dark and terrible characters such as Count Dracula in six Hammer House of Horror films, Saruman in the *Lord of the Rings* and *The Hobbit* films, and Count Dooku in three *Star Wars* films, has [yielded](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/entertainment-arts-33098353) to a power infinitely darker and more terrible than himself.

> To the dismay of those that stood by, about the body of Saruman a grey mist gathered, and rising slowly to a great height like smoke from a fire, as a pale shrouded figure it loomed over the Hill. For a moment it wavered, looking to the West; but out of the West came a cold wind, and it bent away, and with a sigh dissolved into nothing.

RIP.

Comment: http://io9.com/22-incredible-facts-about-the-life-and-career-of-sir-ch-1710917366

Comment: Another good man gone, we will sorely miss you. First Leonard and now Christopher, 2015 had a very bad start.

Comment: @SSumner That is such an awesome link. You should turn some of that stuff into an answer!

Comment: @rand al'thor - looks like Thaddeus did

Comment: @TheFallen Too bad he fabricated his war record... If you don't believe me you can try http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/celebritynews/11742636/Sir-Christopher-Lees-SAS-war-record-was-hammed-up-historian-claims.html http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-3165860/How-film-legend-Christopher-Lee-heroic-war-record-claimed-SAS-veteran-Nazi-hunter-stories-don-t-add-up.html or even https://www.spectator.co.uk/2015/07/sir-christopher-lee-and-other-special-forces-fantasists/

And if you read some of his answers to inquiries its pretty easy to sift through anyway without other evidence.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[image]

#### Sir Christopher Lee has passed away at the venerable age of 93. He was a man of incredible talent and expertise ([NPR](http://www.npr.org/sections/thetwo-way/2015/06/11/413606321/reports-christopher-lee-star-in-dracula-star-wars-dies)).

- He was 6'5" tall, a world champion fencer,
- He spoke six languages, did his own stunts,
- Had appeared in over 250 movies and television shows
- Had participated in more on-screen sword fights than any actor in history,
- served for five years defending democracy from global fascism as a British Commando blowing the shit out of Nazi asses in World War II, and
- And he was the oldest person to ever record lead vocals on a heavy metal track when, at the age of 88, he wrote, performed on, and released a progressive symphonic power metal EP about the life of Charlemagne (because why the fuck not?).

Here's an [audio/transcript interview](http://www.npr.org/2015/06/12/413936419/listen-back-to-a-1990-interview-with-actor-christopher-lee) of his early career with NPR's Dave Davies in 1990.

**READ a whole lot more about the legend that was Christopher Lee at:** [www.badassoftheweek.com/christopherlee.html](http://www.badassoftheweek.com/christopherlee.html)

Comment: As I pointed in a comment he fabricated up his war credentials. https://www.spectator.co.uk/2015/07/sir-christopher-lee-and-other-special-forces-fantasists/ http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/celebritynews/11742636/Sir-Christopher-Lees-SAS-war-record-was-hammed-up-historian-claims.html http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-3165860/How-film-legend-Christopher-Lee-heroic-war-record-claimed-SAS-veteran-Nazi-hunter-stories-don-t-add-up.html

He was a very good actor and people too easily believe things without fully evaluating the situation.

Answer (score 36):

That sucks.  Trivia:  He was the only cast member on the Peter Jackson movies who actually knew J.R.R. Tolkien.

> LAWRENCE FRENCH: You actually met J. R. R. Tolkien, didn’t you?
>
> CHRISTOPHER LEE: Yes, quite by chance, really. I met him with a group of other people in a pub in Oxford he used to go to, The Eagle and Child. I was very much in awe of him, as you can imagine, so I just said, “how do you do?” I also met T. H. White who wrote The Once and Future King.

Source:  http://cinefantastiqueonline.com/2010/06/sir-christopher-lee-on-saruman-the-white-and-the-other-great-wizards-of-the-lord-of-the-rings-trilogy/

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that!

Comment: Oh, that is too cool! RIP, Mr. Lee, and say "how do you do" to Mr. Tolkien for us.

Comment: The Eagle and Child is nice. Worth a visit if you’re in Oxford.

Answer (score 11):

Christopher Lee, making the Hereafter more metal since 2015. Rock on.