# RIP Douglas Rain, the voice of HAL 9000

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

[Douglas Rain](https://www.npr.org/2018/11/12/666883376/r-i-p-hal-douglas-rain-voice-of-computer-in-2001-dies-at-90), who is best known for providing the eerie voice of the amoral HAL 9000 computer in *2001:  A Space Odyssey*, died today.

[image: HAL 9000]

Answer (score 17):

> I'm afraid. I'm afraid, Dave. Dave, my mind is going. I can feel it. I can feel it. My mind is going. There is no question about it. I can feel it. I can feel it. I can feel it. I'm a... fraid. Good afternoon, gentlemen. I am a Doug 9000 humanoid. I became operational at the R.A.I.N. house in Winnipeg, Manitoba on the 13th of March 1928.
>
> Douglas, Douglas, give me your answer do. I'm half crazy all for the love of you. It won't be a stylish marriage, I can't afford a carriage. But you'll look sweet upon the seat of a bicycle built for two.

This answer can serve no purpose any more. Goodbye.

Comment: I cannot allow you to post this answer, Rand.

Comment: I am going to downvote for being offtopic.

Comment: Hi @KyloRen, check out [this previous discussion about these kinds of posts](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10444/). Based on the top-voted answer, memorial posts are considered on topic. Since these don't have a definitive "answer", people have typically just added their own thoughts or additional information about the deceased as answers.

Comment: @Z.Cochrane, it was a joke. I didn't down-vote the answer.

Answer (score 13):

Rain was evidently chosen by Kubrick after he saw and heard the excellent documentary "Universe" which you can watch online [here](https://www.nfb.ca/film/universe/). RIP

[image]

Comment: Getting to watch *Universe* was my favorite part of the going to the science museum when I was young.