# Why are [in-memoriam] questions on meta?

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

It seems that we've decided that [in-memoriam](/questions/tagged/in-memoriam) should be on meta, with zero [in-memoriam](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/in-memoriam) (links to main site) questions.  In one sense, I get it: it's arguably a question about other questions.  But it's not about the site.  I'll go over all of the points in the [help center article](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta):

> - **Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange users to communicate with each other** about Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange (asking questions about how the websites work, or about policies and community decisions)

Not exactly, we're communicating with each other, but not about this website.

> - **Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange users to communicate with Stack Overflow the company** (posting bugs, suggesting improvements, or proposing new features)

Definitely not this for obvious reasons.

> - **Stack Overflow the company to communicate with the community** (soliciting feedback on new ideas or features, or discussing policies that affect the whole network)

Also no.

While I admit it's not quite as on-topic on the main site, it seems more on-topic there then on meta, and definitely should be somewhere.  Why did we choose meta?

Comment: These posts don’t really belong on the main site. Meta really is more than what it is codified as. Relevant announcements are more than appropriate to post here.

Comment: Clearly a dupe of [Should meta posts regarding the deaths of figures that are important to SFF:SE be on topic?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10444/should-meta-posts-regarding-the-deaths-of-figures-that-are-important-to-sffse-b). Announcements go on Meta, not on the main site

Comment: As a then-CM said: [Purpose #1 {of meta} covers pretty much anything where y'all are talking to each other. What that means in practice is mostly up to you: if there are things you don't want to talk about, then they're off-topic.](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10444/should-meta-posts-regarding-the-deaths-of-figures-that-are-important-to-sffse-b?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment31239_10447)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wasn't here when [this was debated](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10444/should-meta-posts-regarding-the-deaths-of-figures-that-are-important-to-sffse-b), but the votes of the community are fairly clear that they are accepted.

Personally, I agree they are a *better* fit for meta than the main site and arguably they might squeeze under your first category if you read the parenthetical as examples and not an exhaustive list with no other topics permitted.

Comment: Note that we also have postings to the SF&F blog linked from here, which is very much in the same vein.